# Countable union and finite intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of subsets of $\Omega$. Let $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma}$ denote the countable union of sets in $\mathcal{F}$. In the same manner, let $\mathcal{F}_d$ denote the finite intersection of sets in $\mathcal{F}$.

Here is the question: Let's consider the collection $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma d}=(\mathcal{F}_\sigma)_d$. I have to show the collection of sets isn't necessarily closed under countable unions.
I'm looking for a hint. I tried the obvious collection of sets for $\mathcal{F}$: open sets, closed sets, etc..

Comment: "countable collection of sets in F [sic]"??

Comment: Yes, countable collection of all sets in $\mathcal{F}$. Not sure if that answers your question though?

Comment: The point of the previous comment was that the phrase "the countable collection of sets in $\mathcal{F}$" is incomprehensible.  *Which* countable collection of sets in $\mathcal{F}$?  Your reply that it is "countable collection of all sets in $\mathcal{F}$" makes it sound like you just mean $\mathcal{F}_\sigma=\mathcal{F}$ and that $\mathcal{F}$ is countable, which seems strange.

Comment: Are you attempting to say that $\mathcal F_\sigma$ is the collection of all countable unions of sets in $\mathcal F$?  And that $\mathcal F_d$ is the collection of all finite intersection of sets in $\mathcal F$?

Comment: Yes sorry. I meant what fleablood meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly your question, you only want a counterexample showing that is possible to have $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma d}\neq (\mathcal{F}_{\sigma d})_\sigma$.
Basically, this is the reason why, when we try to generate a topology from a collection of subsets, we first have to take closure with respect to finite intersections and then to arbitrary unions; except that we only take countable unions.
Although you asked it in a purely set-theoretic setting, I'll give a geometrically flavoured answear which I think could be more clear, and it's indeed natural if you have seen a bit of topology.

We can take $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ the union of left and right open halflines, they are respectively of the form $(-\infty,a)$ and $(b,+\infty)$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.
Thus elements in $\mathcal{F}_\sigma$ are halflines, union of two different types of halflines or even all $\mathbb{R}$.

If we take  $I_1,I_2\in\mathcal{F}_\sigma$ such that $I_i=(-\infty,a_i)\cup 
 (b_i,+\infty)$ where $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$ then
$I_1\cap I_2=(-\infty, \min\{a_1,a_2\})\cup (\max\{b_1,b_2\},+\infty)\cup (\min\{b_1,b_2\},\max\{a_1,a_2\})$.
For example, if $a_1=-\infty$, $b_2=+\infty$ and $a_2>b_1$ we get $I_1\cap I_2=(b_1,a_2)$.

Then in $(\mathcal{F}_{\sigma d})_\sigma$ there can be countable disjoint unions of these intervals, like $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(n,n+1)$.
But, iterating intersections, an element in $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma d}$ can only contain a finite number of bounded intervals in the form $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathcal{F}_{\sigma d}\neq (\mathcal{F}_{\sigma d})_\sigma$.

Comment: Yes, you understood the question correctly. And now I also know where I confused myself as I also found a counter-example thinking it wasn't actually a good one. Thanks!